# Make classes public, but remain private to a JAR file

Tags: java, maven, java-11, java-platform-module-system

Is there a way to make a Java class public but only public with a JAR file? AKA, it's not package private, instead it's package public, but it's not JAR public?

Say I have a structure like this:

```
project/
  package1/
    One.java
  package2/
    Two.java
  package3/
    Three.java
```

Since the 3 .java files are in different packages, I need to make things public. But is there a way to make them only public to the JAR that will contain the project? Such that if another project imports the JAR, it can't see certain public classes/field?

Comment: Yes. A module, introduced in Java 9. Or move the files to the same package.

Answer (score 8):

Using project [Jigsaw](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/) in Java 9 you can do exactly that where you can decide on the packages you want to export. For example:

```
module com.yourproject {
  exports com.yourproject.package1;
}
```

This will make sure that only `package1` is exported.

Answer (score 3):

Pointed already by existing answers, the way to adapt to this is *modularising your code* (adding a module declaration with `module-info.java` for a start). Just detailing them out with reference to [sotms#module-declaration](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#module-declarations)

> `exports` clauses can be added to declare that the module makes all,
>   and only, the `public` types in specific packages available for use by
>   other modules:

```
module com.foo.bar {
    requires org.baz.qux;
    exports com.foo.bar.alpha;
    exports com.foo.bar.beta; 
}
```

> If a module’s declaration contains *no exports clauses* then it will *not export any types at all to any other modules*.

and from the JLS section [Exported and Opened packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7.2)

> The `exports` directive specifies the name of a package to be exported
>   by the current module. For code in other modules, this grants access
>   at compile time and run time to the `public` and `protected` types in the
>   package, and the `public` and `protected` members of those types (§6.6).
>   It also grants reflective access to those types and members for code
>   in other modules.

and further related to qualified and unqualified exports...

> For a qualified directive, the public and protected types in the
>   package, and their public and protected members, are accessible solely
>   to code in the modules specified in the to clause. The modules
>   specified in the `to` clause are referred to as friends of the current
>   module. For an unqualified directive, these types and their members
>   are accessible to code in any module.

Comment: so you just throw this module.java file there somewhere? could you perhaps show how thr structure might look?

Comment: @AlexanderMills here is an [official quick start](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start) guide for that. You keep that file at the project level in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Java 9 introduced modules which are designed to solve this kind of problem.